# What is the best service for Continuous integration for Android apps

Tags: android, continuous-integration

I am starting a new project and I am not sure which CI service should I use, I know just Hockeyapp, ending in few days and AppCenter should substitute it and some of the Firebase features. 
Do you have any experience with other services? What is the best setup for Android CI?

Comment: Bitrise.io is also a good option.
Based on your billing plan, you can opt it.

I have used Hockey app For CD process.

Comment: Thank you. Will look at it.